# How does python guess the parameter in a function being defined without me defining it?

Tags: python

I was covering some of my older steps today to do with lists and one of those was writing a simple practice list for a script:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'raspberry', 'banana']

for fruit in fruits:
     print(fruit)
```

I get this

```
apple
raspberry
banana
```

Simple enough, but as put in bold, fruit hasn't been defined yet. So how did python know what I was talking about?

What is stranger is that when I run the code with it **not** being `fruit` I get a different answer. For example if I write

```
for w in fruits:
     print(fruit)
```

I get

```
banana
banana
banana
```

Why does this happen? Is this python guessing for me? I thought code wasn't supposed to do that.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Using the variable in `for fruit` defines it.

Comment: When you do the second loop, `fruit` still has the last value that was assigned to it in the first loop. So you keep printing that value.

Comment: yes, it *has* been defined, right here: `for fruit in fruits`

Comment: Please learn python basics before posting a question. StackOverflow is not for other people to finish your homework; it's to ask for help on problems you cannot solve by just Googling them.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask]( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  The most emphatic isntruction is to *research* an issue before you post here.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There's no guessing; you *gave* it the name when you wrote `for fruit in fruits:`. That says "Loop through `fruits`, and on each loop, assign the next item from `fruits` to the name `fruit` before executing the contents of the loop".

The reason you saw `banana` repeat when you did `for w in fruits:` is because you did it in the same terminal session or script from which you ran `for fruit in fruits:`, and `fruit` continued to be bound to the last value assigned to it in the prior loop (the final value from `fruits`). `w` kept getting rebound to successive items from `fruits`, but you never used it, you just kept using the unchanged value of `fruit`.

Answer (score 0):

`for fruit in fruits:`

is the start of a loop.  The first time through the loop, Python picks the first value of `fruits` and assigns `fruit` to that value. The second time through the loop, it picks the second value of `fruits` and reassigns `fruit` to that value. Finally, the same thing happens for the third value in the loop.

No guessing is going on.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But then why is that that if I instead impute `w` or something I get a different output?

Comment: normally, if you ran that from scratch, it would error on the line `print(fruit)` as `fruit` isn't defined. In your case, you ran it after you had ran the first loop, which means `fruit` was still assigned to `banana`

Comment: Because you are not printing the w? if you write ```print(w)``` you will get the intended answer, as to you why you are getting banana, it's probably because you are writing this after your first loop, in a fresh program, that banana will not show up

Answer (score -1):

it should be
for w in fruits:
print(w)

Comment: But his question is why it works when he writes `print(fuit)`